# Efficient genetic algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithm

Considering this problem : Having a vector of 1000 real positive numbers,find the optim partition of the 1000 elements in 7 parts so that the sum of parts have aproximative(close) values.

How would you make the chromosome representation, operators (mutation,crossover), fitness function, selection.. so that you solve the problem in the most efficent & optimized way ?

My idea is to give each number a index (the lowest number has index 1, the highest has index 1000 for example)... but I don't think this is the most efficent way? Any suggestions are welcome !

Answer (score 0):

Since its a partition problem I think you need to have the whole set in a single chromosome. Say you have an array of length 1000 that can have values from 1 to 7. The fitness function can calculate the difference of the sum of every partition (less is better). Crossover can be done with single point or double point. Then mutation can randomly change an individual gene from its value to a random value, say position 102 is 4, then mutates to 1. With this solution you guarantee that every chromosome is a valid solution, altough possibly a bad one, so you don't have to check after every iteration for chromosomes that do not follow the problem rules (a problem you would have if you choose to have one chromosome per partition). As usual the criteria for crossover and the likelihood of mutation needs exploration and tunning before achiving best performance.